# Outlook version market share vs. type of Add-in to build

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

We are a cybersecurity startup currently building our product where one of the component involved is an Add-in for Outlook Client. I'm trying to figure out the type of Add-in to build - older COM vs. latest Javascript based. Our target customers are Enterprises and SMBs.

I'm looking for stats on which version of Outlook Client and Outlook server hold the market share (within Microsoft's Email market share) - to justify the type of Add-in to build.

From my understanding, the new Javascript based Add-ins work in Outlook 2013+ for the Client and Exchange 2013+ for the Server (either on-prem or on O365). JS Add-ins work seamlessly across all devices and even OWA and Outlook.com. The older COM Add-ins work from Outlook 2000-2016 and only on on-prem Exchange, and not on OWA or online.

Though that seems to imply JS based is what I need to build, market stats show that Outlook 2010 or earlier are 66% of Outlook's market share (according to https://litmus.com/blog/february-2016-email-market-share-mobile-opens-climb-back-to-55).

We plan to release the product later this year (2017).

I couldn't find relevant info here on previous questions except - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34976288/all-in-one-add-in-for-outlook/34982985#34982985)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add some subjective advice to what Dmitry said: many companies have found it necessary to build add-ins for both platforms.  I speak from experience as I build Outlook add-ins full-time and many of my clients are doing this.  When you factor in 400 million Outlook.com users who may not be using Windows Outlook, and X million Outlook for Mac users who can only run Web Outlook add-ins, then it becomes almost a necessity to support those markets.

If your product's features are not limited by the web platform then you can build one add-in only, IF you are comfortable with omitting all non-Exchange and Outlook 2010 and earlier users from your target market.  Or you can have a "light" web version and a full Windows version of your add-in, but of course two different code bases and platforms.

It's not an easy question to answer - but if your goal is to maximize your target audience than building for everyone is the only approach.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Though both yours and Dmitry's answers were pretty much to the point, your answer prompted me to go dig out some Exchange Server  and Outlook client usage stats in the market. 

My use case is - i want my add-in to run as soon as the user clicks on an email to read it. Looks like JS/web based run only when the clicks the add-in and not automatically upon "email read"

My conclusion is - JS/Web based (as of Apr 3, 2017) will not work for my usecase and I'll have to live with COM based alone until JS based gets that feature

Answer (score 0):

COM addins have nothing to do with Exchange. They work fine even in PST/POP3 profiles. Web Addins only work with Exchange.

Maybe what you should ask yourself is whether JS addins will be adequate for the features you are planning to have - they are extremely limited compared to the COM addins.